# Elliptic Curves and cryptography. Recommended Reading

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography, nt.number-theory, textbook-recommendation

I have been studying RSA cryptography and want to extend this to ECC. I am interested in any books on the topic, that start off with basic principles of elliptic curves as I have almost zero knowledge of them. Can you reccomend any books, or combination of books.

(I do have a good working understanding of group theory pre-postgrad level anyway)

Comment: You should have a look at Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves". The new 2nd edition includes a chapter on "algorithmic aspects" and, in particular, Ch XI.4 deals with elliptic curve cryptography. If you are looking for a more elementary treatment, look at Washington's "Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography".

Comment: Silverman is probably too much for the OP. Washington is OK. A couple of cryptography textbooks have chapters on elliptic curves that may be good starting points. Having said all this, I think this if off-topic for MO and I am voting to close.

Comment: I'm not sure why its off topic. 

Comment: Thinking about it, I agree with FV, regarding closure. http://math.stackexchange.com/ should be a good place to ask this.

Comment: JarvisP, I had not seen your comment before mine: The point is that the purpose of this site is *only* research-level questions. However, the site I link to has a broader scope, but is otherwise very similar.  

Comment: See also a previous MO question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25924/introducing-cryptology-to-undergraduates/25937#25937

Comment: See also http://ellipticnews.wordpress.com/2010/12/26/elliptic-curve-cryptography-books/